# Android - Display sim and phone contacts

Tags: c#, android, contacts, android-contacts

I trying to get sim and phone contacts. I succeed with phone contacts (phone contacts & synced contacts) but with sim contacts I fail...
I tried a lot of URI but no one work so I thought that you guys can help me.

```
    private void Click (object sender , EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionPick , Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("content://contacts"));
    intent.SetType (ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);
    StartActivityForResult (intent , SMS_Send.PICK_NUMAR);
}

    protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == SMS_Send.PICK_NUMAR) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null)) {
            Android.Net.Uri uriContact = data.Data;
            ICursor cursor = ManagedQuery (uriContact,null,null,null,null);

            if (cursor.MoveToFirst ()) {
                string NUME_CONTACT = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName));
                string NUMAR_TELEFON = getPhoneNumber (NUME_CONTACT);
                ISharedPreferences NumeNumar = GetPreferences (FileCreationMode.Private);
                ISharedPreferencesEditor Editor = NumeNumar.Edit ();
                Editor.PutString ("NUMAR_TELEFON" , NUMAR_TELEFON);
                Editor.PutString ("NUME_CONTACT" , NUME_CONTACT);
                Editor.Apply ();
            } 

        } 
    }

    public string getPhoneNumber(string name)
    {
        string ret = null;
        string selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName +" like '%" + name +"%'";
        string[] projection = new string[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number };
        ICursor c = ManagedQuery (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri,projection,selection,null,null);
        if (c.MoveToFirst ()) {
            ret = c.GetString (0);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me !

```
public class MyContacts {

public static String getContacts(Context context){

    StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    outBuffer.append("");
    String strOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, strOrder);    
    outBuffer.append("<contacts>");
    if (cur.getCount() > 0 ) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()  ) {

            outBuffer.append("<contact>").
                      append("<fullname>").
                      append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                      append("</fullname>").
                      append("<id>").
                      append(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))).
                      append("</id>").
                      append("</contact>");         
                }
        cur.close();
        }
    outBuffer.append("</contacts>");
    return outBuffer.toString();
 }

public static String getContactByID(Context context,String contact_id){

    StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    outBuffer.append("");
    //Long inizioLettura = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;    
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

    Uri AdressCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI;
    String AdressCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));
        outBuffer.append("<contact>");

        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {   
            outBuffer.append("<phonenumbers>");
            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);
            if(phoneCursor != null)
                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    outBuffer.append("<phonenumber>").
                              append("<number>").
                              append(phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER))).
                              append("</number>");
                    if(phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)) != null){
                         switch (Integer.valueOf(phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)))) {
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("home").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("mobile").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("work").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("work fax").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("home fax").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_PAGER:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("pager").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("other").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("custom").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CALLBACK:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("callback").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CAR:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("car").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("company main").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ISDN:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("ISDN").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("main").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ASSISTANT:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("assistant").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MMS:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("mms").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER_FAX:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("other fax").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_RADIO:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("radio").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TTY_TDD:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("TTY TDD").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_PAGER:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("workpager").append("</type>"); break;
                         }
                         outBuffer.append("</phonenumber>");
                    }
                }

            outBuffer.append("</phonenumbers>");
            phoneCursor.close();
        }
            Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);  
            outBuffer.append("<emails>");
            if(emailCursor != null)
                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    outBuffer.append("<infoemail>").
                              append("<email>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</email>");       

                    if(emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE))!= null){
                         switch (Integer.valueOf(emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)))) {
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("home").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("mobile").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("work").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("other").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_CUSTOM:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("custom").append("</type>"); break;

                         }
                    }
                     outBuffer.append("</infoemail>");
                }
            outBuffer.append("</emails>");
            emailCursor.close();


            Cursor adressCursor = contentResolver.query(AdressCONTENT_URI,  null, AdressCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);                             
            outBuffer.append("<addresses>");
            if(adressCursor!=null)
                while (adressCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    outBuffer.append("<address>").
                              append("<street>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</street>").
                              append("<city>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</city>").
                              append("<country>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</country>").
                              append("<postalcode>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</postalcode>").
                              append("<neighborhood>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</neighborhood>");    
                    if(adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE)) != null){
                        switch (Integer.valueOf(adressCursor.getString(adressCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE)))) {
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("home").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("work").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_OTHER:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("other").append("</type>"); break;
                           case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_CUSTOM:outBuffer.append("<type>").append("custom").append("</type>"); break;

                           }
                    }
                     outBuffer.append("</address>");

                }
            outBuffer.append("</addresses>");

            Cursor orgCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?",new String[]{contact_id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, null);        
            if(orgCursor!=null)
                while (orgCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    outBuffer.append("<organization>").
                              append("<company>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + orgCursor.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</company>").
                              append("<title>").
                              append(ServerData.getStartcdataxml() + orgCursor.getString(orgCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE)) + ServerData.getEndcdataxml()).
                              append("</title>").
                              append("</organization>");                
                }


            orgCursor.close();
            outBuffer.append("</contact>");
            adressCursor.close();


    }
    return outBuffer.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: A little bit hard to understand but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem .. I had to overwrite the intent type with:

```
intent.SetType (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);
```